# Any advice for these downvotes?

Tags: discussion

I immediately got downvoted twice and am still downvoted 40 minutes later. I'm new so if anyone can let me know what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it.

[The Grand Grid I](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86584/the-grand-grid-i)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps some people think that your question is unclear somewhat and/or just bad. It's a good question, but perhaps the way it looks, aka the formatting, looks ugly to some, and as such is a bad question worthy of a downvote.

I would recommend try to make your question as clear as possible. Sometimes, people give a downvote for no good reason. It's happened to me. It's nothing that you can control. It's something that I would advise getting use to here on PSE (Sorry if this comes off in a menacing manner -I'm trying to politely word it).

Answer (score 11):

## I'm one of the downvoters...

...and it *was* originally because it was fairly unclear when you were talking about all the different types of ciphers. It wasn't really the formatting. Now that I see you've edited it, I changed my downvote to an upvote. You have a great puzzle going there! :D